# GO GORM foreign key constraint is not created

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm having issues with creating foreign key constraint for the `Belongs to` relationship.

A struct containing foreign key:

```
type Summary struct {
    Id          string  `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    OwnerId     *string `gorm:"foreignKey:OwnerId references:Id;not null"`
    Title       string
}
```

Struct to which summary belongs to:

```
type Owner struct {
    Id        string `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Name      string
}
```

It creates the tables in SQL without a problem but SQL schema doesn't contain foreign key constraint in the summary table on the `owner_id` column and therefore Summary can be inserted when an owner doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What eventually worked but not the perfect solution in my opinion is referencing the `Owner` struct inside `Summary` like so:

```
type Summary struct {
    Id          string  `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    OwnerId     string 
    Owner       Owner   `gorm:"foreignKey:OwnerId"`
    Title       string
}
```

I wonder if it's the only way to do so

Comment: Yeah, that's what you need to do, according to the docs [gorm belongsTo](https://gorm.io/docs/belongs_to.html)

Answer (score 0):

What version of gorm are you using? If you are on v1 of the library, try switching to v2. I experienced similar issues while using v1 of the library.

v1 dependency download

```sh
go get -u github.com/jinzhu/gorm
```

v2 dependency download

```sh
go get -u gorm.io/gorm
```

Comment: I use the latest one  gorm.io/gorm v1.21.7